# Why does adding a Selected value to my SelectList cause a model change / migration error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following code runs perfectly for creating a `SelectList` of my Categories.

```
 var categoryList = _context.Category.Select(f => new SelectListItem
 {
    Value = f.ID.ToString(),
    Text = f.CategoryName
 });
```

---

Now I wanted to default the `SelectList` with the current category when editing an item.

```
 var categoryList = _context.Category.Select(f => new SelectListItem
 {
    Value = f.ID.ToString(),
    Text = f.CategoryName,
    Selected = (f.ID == itemModel.category.ID)   // <- added this line
 });
```

---

But I get this error:

[image]

---

If I just shortcut it for testing purposes like this: `Selected = (true)` the code runs again without error.

Why would adding the bool check `f.ID == itemModel.category.ID` cause a model change?  Both left and right hand values are int.  How can I fix this?

---

P.S. Just for grins I tried adding a migration and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL always tries to build a SQL query from your clauses, statements and conditions, and then it runs that query. But in this case it can't convert your code to SQL, because the code refers to an object not available in that context.

**Solution:**
Replace `_context.Category.Select(...)` with `_context.Category.ToList().Select(...)`.

The condtions are now evaluated on the List of objects, instead of on the database.

Comment: This also worked and makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is because EF is unable to translate that expression in SQL.

The simplest way is to create a [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.) using its constructor overload like:

```
var categoryList = new SelectList(_context.Category.ToList(),
                                  "ID", // data value field
                                  "CategoryName", // data text field
                                   itemModel.category.ID   // selected value
                                 );
```

Comment: That solved it!  Any idea why the other method caused the error?

Comment: ef is not able to convert that condition to sql